# Is there a way to send log.html,report.html and output.xml in email after test completion in robot-framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to achieve one scenario in which i need to send log.html, report.html and output.xml directly in the email after completion of test suite and test case. I saw discussions on this part but not able to get the proper answer.

My questions are:

1. How we are able to achieve this task if its possible?
2. If we are not able to achieve then what's the alternate way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new metrics report release thanks to adiralashiva8.

The metrics provide more information including graphs.

This could be an alternative for your problem.

It supports email sending:

To send emails using the new metrics you would need to change the robotmetrics.py file with your email:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com:587')
msg = MIMEMultipart() 
msg['Subject'] = 'MyProject Automation Status'

sender = 'sample@sample.com'
recipients = ['sampleuser@sample.com']
```

You can find more info here:

[New metrics](https://github.com/adiralashiva8/robotframework-metrics)

Update:

To run your metrics after test execution you can use the following command

```
 robot test.robot && robotmetrics
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how to run robot scripts in command line using robot metrics.I tried to run but i am getting issues here.Will you give any example for that ?

Comment: You cannot run the robot scripts with the `robotmetrics` command. You have to run the scripts with the `robot` command first and then run the `robotmetrics` command to generate the results.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Jenkins **Post-build Actions**

[image]